# spring-data-jpa hibernate : failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, lazy-loading

I am getting this error(intermittently) when I tried to lazily read a list of child entities.

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: G.h, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I have gone through a list of posts on SO, regarding this error. All I could find is to do EAGER fetch or to use `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` property. I do not want to do either as they are anti patterns.

And I do have `@Tranastional(readOnly=true)` on the class level where I am reading the data from database, so I would expect the hibernate session to be open till the transaction is complete.

Further more, this error pops up only once in a while. Most of the times there are no issues at all. One more thing is that, I can confirm the entities are loaded lazily(except for place where i have EAGER specified explicitly) as I can see the sql statements being logged, as and when the entities are read.

Here is how my code looks like in a nut shell.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class AService {

 public void someMethod(Long id) {
        Optional<A> a = ARepository.findById(id); // This is a standard JPA repository interface where I have defined a method findById
        final Optional<G> g = getG(a.get());

        if (g.isPresent()) {
            for (final H h : g.get().getH()) { // Exception is thrown exactly at line ..getH()
               
            }
        }
        
    }

    private Optional<G> getG(final A a) {
        return a.getB()
                .getD()
                .getF()
                .flatMap(F::getG);
    }
}

@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private AGroup aGroup;

    @Transient
    public Optional<B> getB() {
        return getC().map(C::getB);
    }

    public Optional<C> getC() {
        if (aGroup != null) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(aGroup.getC());
        }

        return empty();
    }
}


@Entity
public class AGroup implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private C c;

    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "aGroup")
    private final Set<A> as = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
public class C implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "c")
    private List<AGroup> aGroups = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "b")
    private Set<C> cs = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    private D d;
}


@Entity
public class D implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "d")
    private final List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();

    public Optional<F> getF() {
        // based on some other fields return Optional.of(F)
    }
}

@Entity
public class F implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private G g;

    public Optional<G> getG() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(g);
    }
}

@Entity
public class G implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "g")
    private List<F> fs = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "g")
    private List<H> hs = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class H {

    @ManyToOne
    private G g;
}
```

Anyone has any idea what is causing this issue (even more important is, why does this happen intermittently)

I am using spring-data-jpa. This is a spring-boot project. The request comes from the web layer(Rest Controller)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the underlying Hibernate session is closed/reopened at some point which makes `G` detached. I don't know what `ARepository.findById` does or what kind of interceptors you have.

Comment: thanks for the reply. there are no interceptors. ARepository is a JpaRepository which is defined like this 

`public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    Optional<A> findById(Long id);
}`

Comment: You can put a breakpoint into the constructor or the close method of `SessionImpl` to see where an instance is created/closed to further debug this. If that doesn't help, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.